# Could this be the firestore bug?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-console

I tried many different rules. But I am getting permission error.

[image]

But if I add this rule it works

```
   service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if true;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem in the screenshot and/or rules that you shared?

Comment: The rules I wrote don't work. No problem with the rules. The test result is "successful". But I can't get data. I am getting permission error.

Comment: I think I finally found a solution.
Thanks for your time
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules

Comment: Great to hear your found the cause Alpay. Note though there's no way we could've helped you here, as you never showed the code where the problem occurs. For future questions about rules, I highly recommend including the code where you have the problem - as I thought you were asking why the playground allowed the read here.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this. I'm having a problem with the collectionGroup function.

// permission error

```
this.fs.collectionGroup('screts', ref => ref.where("uid", "==", uid));
```

// no any error. I getting data

```
this.fs.doc('channels/zs2wJE3uBR62tqslJJe9').collection('screts').doc('scret_fields')
```

Comment: I think I finally found a solution. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules